# SQLITE group by

Tags: sqlite, group-by

I use the sql below in sqlite to group by time intervals.  The first is group by day and the second group by hour:

```
select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%00:00:00.000', date_time),line, count() from entry group by strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%00:00:00.000', date_time)

select strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', date_time),line, count() from entry group by strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:00:00.000', date_time)
```

How do I group by 10 minutes interval

Comment: Just to be clear: every 10 min with every day - or just every 10 min interval regardless of day?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.  The idea is to group records by time intervals.  The queries I listed do group by one day, and group by one hour.  Now I need group by 10 minutes.  So If I have records inserted over a week, I still want to group them by 10 minutes.  I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 10):

```
 select ... from entry
 group by strftime('%Y%m%d%H0', date_time) + strftime('%M', date_time)/10;
```

Comment: It should be `||` instead of `+` there - otherwise it will treat results of both `strftime`s as numbers and add them together, resulting in a rather hard to trace bug.